# Keeping Only One radio Button Checked In an TableRow Inflater?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout, android-inflate

I have been trying to keep only one of the radio buttons checked but every time the user is able to select multiple radio buttons.

How can I keep just a single or the current selected radio button checked?

I basically have a `TableLayout` which has a `TableRow` as an XML layout being inflatd from code. Also, an `onClickListener` is applied on the RadioButton which fetches the `tag` for the current selected Radio Button.

Can someone please help me out with this?

For ref. my Table Row's XML Layout:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                        android:id="@+id/tblDynStoreRow"
                        android:layout_margin="0.0dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvStoreCount"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="12dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rb1StoreName"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="31dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
                    </TableRow>
```

onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_selection);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainstoretable);
    //RadioButton rb1;

    TextView TVdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1_date2);

    Intent getStorei = getIntent();
    // UsrGPSLock = i.getStringExtra("currUsrLat") + "," +
    // i.getStringExtra("currUsrLon");
    uuid = getStorei.getStringExtra("imei").trim();

    userDate = getStorei.getStringExtra("userDate");
    TVdate.setText(userDate);

    /*TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();*/

    Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startQues);

    dbengine.open();

    storeList = dbengine.FetchStoreList();

    dbengine.close();

    /*final String[] storeCode = new String[storeList.length];
    final String[] storeName = new String[storeList.length];*/

    storeCode = new String[storeList.length];
    storeName = new String[storeList.length];

    for (int splitval = 0; splitval <= (storeList.length - 1); splitval++) {
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(storeList[splitval]), "_");

        storeCode[splitval] = tokens.nextToken().trim();
        storeName[splitval] = tokens.nextToken().trim();

    }

    System.out.println(storeList);

    // Get the TableLayout
    /*TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);*/

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    // Go through each item in the array

    for (int current = 0; current <= (storeList.length - 1); current++) {


        TableRow storeRow = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_table_row, tl, false);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.tvStoreCount);
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.rb1StoreName);

        //tv1.setTag(current);

        tv1.setText((""+(current+1)).trim());

        //tv1.setId();

        rb1.setTag(storeCode[current]);
        rb1.setText(storeName[current]);

        tl.addView(storeRow);

        /*// Create a TableRow and give it an ID
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        tr.setId(200 + current);
        tr.setTag(storeCode[current]);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setClickable(true);

        rb1 = new RadioButton(this);

        rb1.setId(current);
        rb1.setTag(storeCode[current]);
        rb1.setText(storeName[current]);
        rb1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rb1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(rb1);

        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
        cb1.setId(500 + current);
        // cb1.setText(provinces[current]);
        cb1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        cb1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(cb1);


         * CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(this); cb2.setId(300+current);
         * //cb1.setText(provinces[current]); cb2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         * cb2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         * LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); tr.addView(cb2);


        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*/

        rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("inside-onClick");
                //System.out.println(arg0.getId());
                System.out.println(arg0.getTag());
                selStoreID = arg0.getTag().toString();

                if(prevSel == 0) {
                    prevSelStoreID = selStoreID;
                    prevID = arg0.getId();
                    prevSel = 1;
                }
                else{

                }
                /*rb1.refreshDrawableState();*/

                if(prevSelStoreID.equals(arg0.getTag().toString())){
                    /*int rbID;
                    rbID = rb1.getId();
                    System.out.println("RB ID: " + rbID);*/

                }
                else{
                    int rbID;
                    rbID = arg0.getId();

                    //rb1.refreshDrawableState();
                    //rb1.clearFocus();
                    //rb1.findViewById(rbID).isSelected();

                    rb1.findViewById(prevID).clearFocus();
                    rb1.findViewById(prevID).invalidate();
                    rb1.findViewById(prevID).refreshDrawableState();

                    System.out.println("prevID: " + prevID);
                    System.out.println("rbID: " + rbID);

                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    //rb1.findViewWithTag(prevSelStoreID).invalidate();

                    prevSel = 0;
                    prevSelStoreID = selStoreID;
                    prevID = rbID;

                    rb1.findViewById(rbID).isSelected();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent nxtP3 = new Intent(StoreSelection.this, LastVisitDetails.class);
            nxtP3.putExtra("storeID", selStoreID);
            nxtP3.putExtra("imei", uuid);
            nxtP3.putExtra("date", userDate);
            startActivity(nxtP3);


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: please add getView() method code

Comment: @Krit Please see my updated code; I have added flags for current selected and prev. selected radio button.

Comment: every time user click on radiobutton. you must update selected flag value and fill the listview again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent multiple checking of RadioButton they must be all within the same RadioGroup.

Either you define a Radiogroup in your XML (but from what I see you are trying to do it will be difficult)

or you create it in Java: `RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);`

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Try this...hope it works

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[storeList.length];
for (int current = 0; current <= (storeList.length - 1); current++) {


    TableRow storeRow = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_table_row, tl, false);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.tvStoreCount);
    rb[current]  = (RadioButton)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.rb1StoreName);
    rg.addView(rb[current]);
    /*other suff...
```

Comment: but won't that (`define create it in Java: RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(....`) be difficult too? Can you point me to a sample for the same?

Comment: ` rb[current]  == (RadioButton)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.rb1StoreName);` is it this: ` rb[current]  = (RadioButton)storeRow.findViewById(R.id.rb1StoreName);` ?

Comment: @embeddedEnthusiast if any of these answer helped you accept one by clicking the green check on the left, and/or upvote them by clicking the up-pointing orange arrow on the left. Cheers. maurizio

Comment: srry for late reply..nvm I got it myself..still marking it as answer and +1 ..very..very helpful :)

Comment: @embeddedEnthusiast thanks! And good luck with your work! Maurizio